# <a> href information from a form field for signature template webpage not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working on a signature template page for my companies Intranet and have managed to get it working and looking almost how I want.

I'm trying to get link information updated from my forms without changing the displayed text.

I did manage to get it to change the `href` but it's adding extra info in the `href` that's not needed.

Here's the link to my code https://jsfiddle.net/kogcyb3z/

```js
function writeName() {
  document.getElementById("pName").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-full-name").value;
  document.getElementById("pTitle").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-job-title").value;
  document.getElementById("ad1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-address1").value;
  document.getElementById("ad2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-address2").value;
  document.getElementById("oPhone").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-office-phone").value;
  document.getElementById("mPhone").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-mobile-phone").value;
  document.getElementById("fNumber").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-fax-number").value;
  document.getElementById("lNumber").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sig-license-number").value;
  document.getElementById("sFile").href = document.getElementById("sig-sharefile").value;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

h2.sig-header {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.sig-input-form {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px
}

.sig-preview-name {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.sig-input-label {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.sig-input-field {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.sig-preview-title {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.sig-preview-info {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.sig-preview-links {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.button-label {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0
}

.button-generate {
  color: #0F2A3B;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0 border: 3px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.sig-input-field {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dedede;
  color: #555 !important;
  font-family: "Calibri" !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 9px !important;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  height: 38px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.sig-input-form {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}

.sig-control.half-width.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}

.sig-control.half-width.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%
}

.sig-control.left {
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}

#sig-preview {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<h2 class="sig-header">Your Information</h2>
<div class="sig-input-form">
  <div class="sig-control half-width left">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-full-name">Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-full-name" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width right">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-job-itle">Job Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-job-title" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width left">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-address1">Street Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-address1" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width right">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-sig-address2">City, State Zip</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-address2" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width left">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-office-phone">Office Phone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-office-phone" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width right">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-mobile-phone">Mobile Phone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-mobile-phone" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width left">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-fax-number">Fax Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-fax-number" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width right">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-email">Email Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-email" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width left">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-license-number">License Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-license-number" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sig-control half-width right">
    <div class="sig-label">
      <label class="sig-input-label" for="sig-sharefile">ShareFile Link</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sig-input">
      <input class="sig-input-field" id="sig-sharefile" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="sig-preview">
  <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="display: inline;" width="272" height="92" border="0"></div>
  <div>
    <font color="#0F2A3B"><span style="margin:0;font-size:14pt;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri;" id="pName">John Doe</span><span style="margin:0;font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;"> | </span><span style="margin:0;font-size:14pt;font-weight:100;font-family:Calibri;"
        id="pTitle" class=sig-preview-title>Widget Maker</span></font>
  </div>
  <div style="margin:0;font-size:11pt;font-weight:100;font-family:Calibri;font-style=normal">
    <font color="#0F2A3B"><span id="ad1">101 Anywhere Court, Suite 203</span><span> | </span><span id="ad2">Anytown, ST 55555</span>
      <div>tel: <span id=oPhone>555-555-5555</span> | cell: <span id=mPhone>555-555-6666</span> | fax: <span id=fNumber>555-555-6666</span></div>
    </font>
    <div style="margin:0;font-size:11pt;font-weight:100;font-family:Calibri;font-style=normal">
      <font color="#0F2A3B"><span>NMLS# </span><span id="lNumber">123456</span></font>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:0;font-size:9pt;font-weight:100;font-family:Calibri;">
      <font color="#1F4E79"><span><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://google.com/" target="_blank"><span>Website</span></a>
        |
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://maps.google.com" target="_blank"><span>Map</span></a> |
        <span><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:john.doe@google.com" target="_blank">Email</a></span> |
        <span><a id="sFile" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://google.sharefile.com/r-rdf834da7a8149478" target="_blank">Send me large files using Sharefile</a></span></span>
      </font>
    </div>

    <div class="sig-control-right">
      <div class="button-label">
        <span><br> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="button-input">
        <button class="button-generate" onclick="writeName()">Generate Signature</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are expecting a URL of the format

```
https://google.sharefile.com/r-rdf834da7a8149478
```

in the sharefile link.

Your code only puts in the exact entry from the form field. It shows up incorrectly when you hover since the browser thinks it is a URI relative to the current page.

So update it to be:

```
var sigval = document.getElementById("sig-sharefile").value;
sigval = 'https://google.sharefile.com/' + sigval;
document.getElementById("sFile").href = sigval;
```

Comment: Dude you're blowing my mind. It actually was working correctly. I just wasn't inputing the website information in the needed format like you pointed out. As soon as I used the full https://example.com it output that to the field.

which is actually what I need, since users will be copying the whole address from the sharefile link they create with the Outlook plugin.

That also helped me see how to do the email field, I just needed to make the code so it appended the mailto: to the document object.

href = "mailto:"+document.getElementById("sig-email").value;